# .NET application configured on IIS, recycling clean-up

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I have written one .Net Application recently which is deployed on IIS. The application is collecting timely data from the data server. Application internally use multiple HTTP connection and application-level caching to improve the application performance.

The recycling is configured with one day interval. I have noticed that whenever IIS manager recycled the service, the newer application does not have any cache data. I have two questions related to this.

1. Is the case, whenever application get recycled it will not have any cache data which are used on previous instance?
2. On application recycle, will it release all the HTTP connection which are present on the application.

Also, is there any way to preserve the application state to newly created instance after recycling process happens?

Please let me if any questions are ambiguous.

Comment: See if you know what are "in-process/in-memory caching" and "out of process caching". Search about them and you will find the answers to your questions in previous discussions.

Comment: @Eldar Thanks for the answer. I have question on similar line.

1. Is there any way to close such connection, like clean-up methods, before it stop the old container?

This is important, as my application have multiple HTTP connection with system/site. And there is imitated connection available. So, if application recycle and connection will be still open then it can create issues.

Comment: I couldn’t understand your requirement clearly, what is your purpose for doing this?

Comment: @samwu Hi, Basically I want to way to maintain application state even after recycling take place. 

If that's not possible, then there will be many open HTTP connection in old container for application, So is there any way to close the HTTP connection when application recycle take place so there will be no handing open HTTP connections.

Comment: As far as I know, this is impossible.